# Problem - file with a size but no content?

Tags: file

today when I working on my site and writing in a .css file suddenly my computer shutdown when I turn it on and open the .css file I working on it was empty but file size of the file was like it is full. How I can restore the content of the file? Please help, I worked on this file almost a week.

Answer (score 0):

the filesize could just be old cached information, if you're using windows press F5 and if the filesize change then your file is gone, then you should ask yourself why didnt you save your css through out the proccess if you did then there's a chance you could retrieve it, search through your temp folders for any css file that might be the file you lost, there is also a ocean of application that helps you retrieve lost documents use google and you'll sure find something

p.s. what happens if you open that file with notepad

Comment: The file size is still the but the content not. I save the file minutes before the computer shutdown and when I turn it on I open the site in my browser and then I see the file is like not loaded and then I see that there is no content. There is a lot of program for file restore but my file is not deleted It just not have content. Do you think this programs are going to help?

Comment: When I open the file with Notepad++ the file is full with "Null" signs.

Comment: if its full with null signs i guess there is some errors in your registry, download a registry repair tool and you should be fine